# Разъяснения по циклу for

Tags: python, for

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Только начинаю изучать питон, но не могу найти разъяснения что представляет собой первая переменная после for? (guessesTaken)

Смысл я понимаю что она перебирает range(), но она сохраняется после фора, не исчезает? Как например если бы мы использовали другой цикл

Я имею ввиду в строках
if guess == secretNumber:
print('верно кол-во попыток..!' + str(guessTaken))
Здесь же эта переменная guessTaken не может существовать или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одласть видимости в Python не ограничивается циклами, как javascript например.

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
print(i)
i=i-3
print(i)
```

############

```
0
1
2
2
-1
```

Но использовать так переменные не рекомендуется, чтобы была читаемость кода, и не путаться.

Comment: Спасибо большое, долго не мог понять сам)